# Will conditionally exporting module allow it to update?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm trying to implement dark mode in an application currently, and I was wondering if I could conditionally export the color component and have it update throughout the app.

I didn't make this app, there's over 250 style sheets that reference this color file, so having conditionals in each of them isn't a viable solution.

Currently it's being exported like this

```
  Alto: '#DADADA',
  Black: '#000000',
  BlackSemiTransparent: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
  BlackFaded: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84)',
  Blue500: '#007DBA',
  Blue600: '#005F8E',
  Blue700: '#005077',
  Blue800: '#007AFF', ... }

export default colors;
```

but if I were to say like

```
    if(state.darkTheme) {
    colors = { dark theme colors }
}
```

and have it update the colors throughout the app or will it not re-import?

If not, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try looking into using `Context` https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html, it's useful for creating a theme system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I every case that I know of, module bundlers only run each module at most once.

I would suggest doing something like

```
export default state => {
  if (state.darkTheme) {
    return { dark theme colors };
  } else {
    return { light theme colors };
  }
};
```

And then using your colors like

```
import colors from './colors';

const red = colors(state).red;
```

This is by no means the only way to do this, it is just the way that I would.